# Creating a controller class for a windows form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-interface, controller

I have a task of refactoring the code backing to a windows form. I need to empty all of the calculations that are being done on the form itself and move them to a controller class. The form will then just make an instance of the controller on creation, and reference the controller's methods in the event handlers. This is supposed to make it easier for unit tests to be performed.

One of the problems that I'm having is that the calculations often check the controls on the form (like textboxes) for data, or check if the controls exist at all. Obviously, the controller won't be able to reference this data under normal circumstances. I was told that I might be able to set this up using properties in the controller class, and do something to have the form bind to the controller, but none of this is familiar to me. I'm still having a hard time understanding exactly what it is that I'm supposed to be doing.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is this for a job or course?

Comment: @Grim It's for a new development job. No matter how many questions I ask I cant get a good understanding from the way its explained to me.

Comment: You need to separate the `logic` from the form first.  Create your controller class as simply as possible, then gradually move the functionality away from the form's controls.  I'm sure someone else can point you at resources that explain that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MVVM pattern that almost everyone uses with WPF and the ASP.NET MVC Framework as examples.  As you use the word "controller", I'd suggest that you need to more closely follow MVC.  You can define a view model class whose job it is to contain the data needed by the view, i.e. the form.  Your controller exposes the view model to the view and works directly with that view model.  If the controller needs to do any validation or the like, it does it on that view model.

The view gets the view model from the controller and binds it to its controls.  If there's ever a need to determine whether a control exists, it's the view's responsibility to do that.

The view model is the model, i.e. the data, that gets used by the view.  That may or may not be the same model that is used at the data access level.  In a highly architected application, your data access code will generate a model and the data gets moved to the application in DTOs and then into view models for actual presentation.  All three might be different shapes in certain cases.